# Solving Functional Equations by Limits ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, functional-equations

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function and satisfying the equation :

$f(2x) - f(x) = x$. Given $f(0)=1$ ; Find $f(3)=?$

My teacher solves this as :

$$f(x) - f(x/2) = x/2$$
$$f(x/2) - f(x/4) = x/4$$
.

.

.

$$f(x/2^{n-1})  - f(x/2^{n}) = x/ 2^{n-1}$$

...........…......
Add them up : And let $n\rightarrow \infty$

$$f(x)  - f(x/2^{n}) =(x/2)/(1-(1/2))$$

Thus $f(x)  - f(0) = x$.

Thus $f(x) = x+1$. Thus $f(3)= 4$.

However my problem is that I didn't find it intuitive ; I didn't understand how to get such an idea.

So is there an alternate way to go about this problem ?

Comment: I can't come up with another idea at the moment. But I think that this is the beauty of Mathematics, now you have another tool in your toolbox to use next time you encounter a similar problem.

Comment: I would say, if the function is differentiable, then the Maclaurin series is: $f(x) = 1+x \Rightarrow f(3)=4$. 

*(However differentiability is not mentioned.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say,

search function $f(x) = x+\mu(x), \quad \mu(x)$ continuous for $x\in R,\,\mu(0)=1$:

$f(2x)-f(x)=x\Rightarrow 2x + \mu(2x) - x - \mu(x)=x\Rightarrow \mu(2x)=\mu(x)$

$\Rightarrow \mu(x) \equiv$ const $= \mu(0) = 1$

$\Rightarrow f(x)=x+1\Rightarrow f(3)=4$

Comment: Nice!! I just wanted to know as to what made you assume that search function?

Comment: @Sudhanshu Something I wrote in a comment on your question. So I tried it.